# What is __argvalue?

Tags: c#, .net, language-extension

> Also, there is one other thing that is an lvalue in VC#, though it's a language extension - __argvalue().

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/19/always-write-a-spec-part-one.aspx#ctl00___ctl00___ctl00_ctl00_bcr_ctl00___Comments___Comments_ctl11_NameLink)

That was the *only* Google result for `__argvalue`.

I tried it in LINQPad and it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: No, this StackOverflow post also appears in Google when searching for "`__argvalue`". :-)

Comment: I was waiting for someone to say that.

Comment: Yeah, Visual Studio recognises the other "secret" C# keywords that I know of - `__arglist`, `__makeref`, `__reftype` and `__refvalue` - and highlights them like any other. No such luck with `__argvalue` though.

Comment: Pavel clearly meant __arglist.  I'll fix the typo.

Comment: How can `__arglist` be an lvalue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can definitively state that there is no `__argvalue` in C# as of .NET Framework 4.0. The compiler binary contains a table of tokens. You can find the other hidden __ prefixed keywords starting at `0x00009840`. However, a search of the *entire* binary shows that there is no `__argvalue` token.

The author of that comment may have been referring to `__arglist`, which can be an lvalue.